# sql error with simple foreign key reference. Field doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

So the foreign key in the customers table is referencing the movieID primary key in the movies table. I don't understand why I am getting an error saying that movieID doesn't exist.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyJBi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **movieID (int not null) field** into the **related table (customers)**. I have seen it is missing in your sql script

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the column in your table customers before adding a foreign key constrait to it.